# Solution for losing dynamic control values on control events

Tags: c#, asp.net, dynamic-controls

I have a gridview in which I populate dropdown lists dynamically. These dropdown lists are filled with data from the database therefore the number of columns and rows of the gridview, and number of dropdown controls are not known beforehand. (I'm using ItemTemplate class which inherits ITemplate to create dynamic dropdown columns).

I am able to display the data correctly but the problem comes when I try to save changed values of the gridview to the database.

I have a button outside the gridview so that when the user clicks on it any saved data should get updated in the database. But on the button click event I am unable to access the values of the dropdown lists as dynamic content is lost on postback and on any other control event.

Can somebody direct me towards a solution for this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: when you are creating dropdown lists ?

Comment: @Antonio Bakula On page load

Answer (score 0):

Study the [ASP .NET page life-cycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) and you will see that you need to create your dynamic controls in **`OnInit`** which is the event for **`PreInit`**, otherwise they will not be available on **`Page_Load`** etc.

Answer (score 0):

You have to create dynamic controls in OnInit event, becouse when OnLoad hits viewstate is allready populated and your newly created controls are not update with data from viewstate.

Here is a good article about viewstate :

http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/archive/2006/08/03/Truly-Understanding-Viewstate.aspx